# PhoneGap Script reads contacts correctly until I include photos (avatars) 

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, cordova

Following script is supposed to return a list of contacts together with their emails, phone numbers and avatars (photos).

It works like a charm it I remove the avatar (photo) retrieval code, the moment I add it back. The script breaks. Does anyone have any experiences trying to display contact photos via phonegap?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Contact Example</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.9.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

        // Wait for Cordova to load
        //
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        // Cordova is ready
        //
        function onDeviceReady() {
            // specify contact search criteria
            var options = new ContactFindOptions();
            options.filter="";          // empty search string returns all contacts
            options.multiple=true;      // return multiple results
            filter = ["displayName", "name", "phoneNumbers"];

            // find contacts
            navigator.contacts.find(filter, onSuccess, onError, options);
        }

        // onSuccess: Get a snapshot of the current contacts
        //
        function onSuccess(contacts) {
            console.log(contacts.length);
            for (var i=0; i<contacts.length; i++) {
                var LI=$("#list").append('<li>'+contacts[i].displayName+'</li>');
                if (contacts[i].phoneNumbers) {
                    for (var j=0; j<contacts[i].phoneNumbers.length; j++) {
                        $(LI).append('<span>'+contacts[i].phoneNumbers[j].value+'</span><Br/>');
                    }
                }
                if (contacts[i].emails) {
                    for (var j=0; j<contacts[i].emails.length; j++) {
                        $(LI).append('<span>'+contacts[i].emails[j].value+'</span><br/>');
                    }
                }
                if (contacts[i].photos) {
                    for (var j=0; j<contacts[i].photos.length; j++) {
                        alert(contacts[i].photos[j].value);
                        //$(LI).append('<span>'+contacts[i].photos[j].value+'</span><br/>');
                    }
                }
                /*if (contacts[i].photos) {
                    for (var j=0; j<contacts[i].photos.length; j++) {
                        $(LI).append('<img src="'+contacts[i].photos[j].value+'"/><br/>');
                    }
                }*/
            }
        };

        // onError: Failed to get the contacts
        //
        function onError(contactError) {
            alert('onError!');
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Example</h1>
    <p>All Contacts in a list</p>
    <ul id="list">
    </ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your filter does not included the "photos" field. Without it being specified the array of photos will not be populated.